# how to insert textbox text to existing excel file? vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

i want to make a program that saves the text in textbox to excel file using loop because i want to insert multiple text to excel. i found codes but it only overwrites data in cells. i want the program to find the last row and insert new data to the next row. im stuck here, please someone help me how to do that in vb.net. here is my code:

```
    Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Excel.screenupdating = True
    Excel.Visible = True

    'fieldnames
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Object = Excel.workbooks.add
    Excel.workbooks(1).worksheets(1).cells(1, 1).value = "TITLE"
    Excel.workbooks(1).worksheets(1).cells(1, 2).value = "AUTHOR"
    Excel.workbooks(1).worksheets(1).cells(1, 3).value = "EDITION"
    Excel.workbooks(1).worksheets(1).cells(1, 4).value = "PUBLISHER"
    Excel.workbooks(1).worksheets(1).cells(1, 5).value = "ISBN"

    'i want to loop here the data in textboxes
    Excel.workbooks(1).worksheets(1).cells(2, 1).value = txtTitle.Text
    Excel.workbooks(1).worksheets(1).cells(2, 2).value = txtAuthor.Text
    Excel.workbooks(1).worksheets(1).cells(2, 3).value = txtEdition.Text
    Excel.workbooks(1).worksheets(1).cells(2, 4).value = txtPublisher.Text
    Excel.workbooks(1).worksheets(1).cells(2, 5).value = txtISBN.Text

    xlWorkSheet.SaveAs(FileName)

    Excel.quit()
    Excel = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

you're going to need to dynamically set the value for the rowindex and the aplha column.
so something like this

```
dim currRow as integer = 0
Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Excel.screenupdating = True
Excel.Visible = True

'fieldnames
Dim xlWorkSheet As Object = Excel.workbooks.add
Excel.workbooks(1).worksheets(1).cells((currRow+1), 1).value = "TITLE"
Excel.workbooks(1).worksheets(1).cells((currRow+1), 2).value = "AUTHOR"
Excel.workbooks(1).worksheets(1).cells((currRow+1), 3).value = "EDITION"
Excel.workbooks(1).worksheets(1).cells((currRow+1), 4).value = "PUBLISHER"
Excel.workbooks(1).worksheets(1).cells((currRow+1), 5).value = "ISBN"
```

currRow += 1

for i as integer = currRow to 5

```
'i want to loop here the data in textboxes
Excel.workbooks(1).worksheets(1).cells((currRow + i), 1).value = txtTitle.Text
Excel.workbooks(1).worksheets(1).cells((currRow + i), 2).value = txtAuthor.Text
Excel.workbooks(1).worksheets(1).cells((currRow + i), 3).value = txtEdition.Text
Excel.workbooks(1).worksheets(1).cells((currRow + i), 4).value = txtPublisher.Text
Excel.workbooks(1).worksheets(1).cells((currRow + i), 5).value = txtISBN.Text
```

next

currRow += 1

```
xlWorkSheet.SaveAs(FileName)

Excel.quit()
Excel = Nothing
```

i don't know if this works but this is something to get you started.

Comment: thanks for your help but my problem is i want to find the last non-empty column and from there insert the new data from 5 textbox. each textbox equals to 1 column. how to do that in loop?